# In .NET Efficiently way to merge string

Tags: .net, string, c#-4.0, merge, union

I'm using .NET 4.0. I have two string , which may share one or more values:

```
string sSet1 = "de§§vent§§n’oubliez§§pas§§d’acheter§§un§§pied§§de"
string sSet2 = "vent§§n’oubliez§§pas§§d’acheter§§un§§pied§§de§§parasol"
```

I'd like a way to merge them into one string

```
"de§§vent§§n’oubliez§§pas§§d’acheter§§un§§pied§§de§§parasol"
```

How can I do this in efficient way?

**EDIT:**
Union function removes duplicates !

With the solution proposed by QTX, result string is

```
"de§§vent§§n’oubliez§§pas§§d’acheter§§un§§pied§§parasol"
```

The second word "de" is missing since removed by the Union() function

Comment: Before asking for the *efficient* one, have you tried anything? Where is your *inefficient* way

Comment: I have tried with IEnumerable<string> but I did not know it was possible to use Union function to do this (proposed by QtX)

Answer (score 1):

You question isn't clear. The closest thing I can think of:

```
var result = String.Join("§§", sSet1.Split(new string[] { "§§" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
                        .Union(sSet2.Split(new string[] { "§§" }, StringSplitOptions.None)));
```

Comment: Qtx, It's OK. This is the solution. Thank's for your help.

Comment: Doesn't work, Union() function remove duplicate ! I edit my question.

Comment: @PapyRef I know. As I said: `The closest thing I can think of`. I don't understand how you want to obtain that string. What is the rule?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use a StringBuilder class. Use it when you have to make lots of concatinations. And in the case if you only need to merge 2-3 strings, string.Format is your option.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have two strings, you could use:

```
string result = string.Format("{0}{1}", sSet1, sSet2);
```

If there are more strings, I would used the StringBuilder class:

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
b.Append( sSet1 );
b.Append( sSet2 );
// append remaining strings
//
string result = b.ToString();
```